# Performance android multiple connection on database

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

this will be a question about performance. First of all sorry for my English, but let's go, I have an application that is a menu from a restaurant.

It is working good but I want to improve, I want it to be fast enough to not be so slow.

For example :

In the first i get "Skipped xx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.”, so i read the best solution is to not put so many large images and do all the connection to database in a Thread or Running.

Here is my code in fragment :

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    controller  = new MDAlacarte(getActivity());
    int idCategoria    = Integer.parseInt(getArguments().getString("idCategoria"));
    int idSubcategoria = Integer.parseInt(getArguments().getString("idSubcategorias"));

    buscarPratos(idCategoria,idSubcategoria);

}

private void buscarPratos(final int idCategoria, final int idSubcategoria ) {

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            //If there are stories, add them to the table

            pratosLista = controller.getPratosPorCategoriaAlacarte(idCategoria,idSubcategoria);
            int tamanho = pratosLista.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho ; i++) {


                pratoObj = new Prato( pratosLista.get(i).get("nome"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("descricao"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("codigo"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("categoria"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("preco"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("tipo"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("subcategoria"));


                pratos.add(pratoObj);
                nomePratos.add(pratosLista.get(i).get("nome"));

            }

        }
    });
}
```

but the problem is that is slow sometimes when i add so many tabs like in the categoria "Drinks" that is "Bebidas" here in brazil and are so slow to perform that, it is like 8 tabs, per example each my fragment execute this code for each tab they have.

This is the best practice? It is a listview and I made the ViewHolder Pattern to have a good performance.

What i missing?

Comment: You don't need `runOnUiThread`  there...

Comment: hum why cricket_007?

Comment: Because that section of code is already on the UI thread from after `onViewCreated`

Comment: What is the best performance? Asyntask can make fast?

Comment: Yes, it **can**, but that doesn't mean whatever you are doing **needs** it

Answer (score 0):

To get the work off the UI Thread, you might want to use an `AsyncTask`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can simply replace `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){...};` by this

```
private void buscarPratos(final int idCategoria, final int idSubcategoria) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @ Override
        public void doInBackground() {
            // If there are stories, add them to the table

            pratosLista = controller.getPratosPorCategoriaAlacarte(idCategoria,idSubcategoria);
            int tamanho = pratosLista.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
                nome = pratosLista.get(i).get("nome")
                pratoObj = new Prato(nome,
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("descricao"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("codigo"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("categoria"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("preco"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("tipo"),
                        pratosLista.get(i).get("subcategoria"));

                pratos.add(pratoObj);
                nomePratos.add(nome);
            }
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

Comment: I use the Asynctask to do connection with internet but not for SQLITE operations.

Comment: Thank you, but now i'm facing another problem my Asynctask function execute before my adapter on create view from my fragment :

How can i execute this before?

Comment: Well, a bit more code would be useful. And could you please restate your problem?